# How to make RestEasy generate http error 400 for wrong query parameters

Tags: resteasy

For some reason ReatEasy generates error 404 when it can't parse query parameters: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Unable to extract parameter from http request.
This even apply for custom ParamConverter that throws BadRequestException. RestEasy likely catches this exception and rethrows NotFoundException instead.
It is a bug or it is configurable ?

Comment: That is part of the spec since it can't match a method. Do you have an example?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Resteasy likely can match a method because arguments with formats of particular method are listed in the body of the 404 response. But if specification is wrong than it can't be help. As for example I passed a text for integer parameter.

Comment: Right yes. Text as an integer parameter would result in no matching, e.g. 404.